# DIP temperature Sensor with serial port

Tags: sensor, integrated-circuit, uart, temperature, dip

I am looking for a temperature sensor which is in for of DIP suitable for breadboards and serial communication that is usable for Arduino.

I am not after a resistive or an analogue sensor.
I am not after anything that contains a PCB board in it either. I am after pure chip. Because, in future, I may decide putting it on a PCB neatly.

I tried a lot searching and found no result. How can I send serial data from a DIP chip to Arduino?

**PS.** This question should not be on hold. To remove excuse, I changed the wording.

Comment: Purchase recommendations are off topic.  Effectively no sensors meeting your other criteria would have a "serial port" in the usual meaning of the term, though there are a variety with sorts of embedded serial interfaces such as I2C, SPI, one wire, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DS18B20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) perhaps ("1 wire" digital temp sensor in TO92 package)

Comment: + 1: the only answer.